# Let $U=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R} \mid x^2<y<e^x \}$. Show that $U$ is open in the plane.

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

> Let $U=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R} \mid x^2<y<e^x \}$. Show that $U$ is open in the plane.

I have that $U = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R} \mid x^2-y<0<e^x-y \}$. Let $f(x,y)=x^2-y$ and $g(x,y)=e^x-y$. Now $U= \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R} \mid f(x,y)<0<g(x,y) \} = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R} \mid f(x,y)<0 \} \cap \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R} \mid g(x,y)>0\}$.

It seems that $U= f^{-1}[(-\infty,0)] \cap g^{-1}[(0,\infty)]$ so it's the union of two open preimages of continuous functions hence open? I'm not sure I've got the preimages right?

Comment: Seems fine to me :) (modulo changing "union" for "intersection")

Comment: Seems fine! Just a small detail: $U$ is the intersection, not the union, of two open sets (but the finite intersection of open sets is open).